# ImportError in GeoPandas

Tags: geopandas

I get the following error when importing GeoPandas. I using pip and anaconda to install GeoPandas, but I still get the same error. What I should do?

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ImportError                               Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-9-b86cb47439ab> in <module>
      4 import numpy as np
      5 from shapely.geometry import mapping
----> 6 import geopandas as gpd
      7 import rasterio as rio
      8 from rasterio.plot import plotting_extent

~/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/geopandas/__init__.py in <module>
      1 from geopandas._config import options  # noqa
      2 
----> 3 from geopandas.geoseries import GeoSeries  # noqa
      4 from geopandas.geodataframe import GeoDataFrame  # noqa
      5 from geopandas.array import points_from_xy  # noqa

~/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/geopandas/geoseries.py in <module>
      7 from pandas.core.internals import SingleBlockManager
      8 
----> 9 from pyproj import CRS, Transformer
     10 from shapely.geometry.base import BaseGeometry
     11 

ImportError: cannot import name 'CRS' from 'pyproj' (/Users/rohullahnajibi/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pyproj/__init__.py)
```

Comment: did you see this? https://stackoverflow.com/a/62958055/1193155

Comment: Yes, but I am not dealing with OSMNX. I get the error when importing geopandas.

Comment: Don't use pip unless you have no option (i.e the package you need is not in the conda repositories).  Geopandas is available in the conda repos, use conda to install it not pip.